# mongodb - does expire data ttl settings actually index and deletes source collection when all docs expire

Tags: mongodb, ttl

I have a question about expire TTL settings on documents.

My use case:

My application is kind of aggregator service. It creates one new collection per source. Sources may come and go (read die). My data access pattern is less number of reads and more number of writes. While some of core collections (which do not change) are indexed, collections that application creates per source are not indexed. Generally whole data or partial subset of data (like just 10 records) from that collection is fetched so no need to index really.

Problem:

Those dynamic collections from sources are getting bigger and after certain period of time, we don't need older documents from these collections. So I was thinking of applying "[expire TTL settings](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)". However, I had few questions around it.

Questions:

1. Does it actually create index which helps in searching. I mean I do not want those documents to be indexed. Currently, I am just fetching all from the collection. That is our use case.
2. Does it also deletes the collection when all documents in that collection are expired. this might be inner details but I thinking having a clue about this would be helpful

Comment: This is not going to reduce the number of writes, however you could store all these sources in the same collection, using "upsert" to "bucket" them and have a background job that delete the old ones.
Have a look at the [aggregate reports use case](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expire TTL settings on a document are implemented and enforced thru an index on a BSON date object with the expireAfterSeconds flag set. So you have to have an index on that field in order to make TTL work. Not certain why you have an issue about indexing the documents but this is the only way that TTL works.

Regarding does the index created help in searching - yes it does. You can test this by creating an index on a date object using expireAfterSeconds and then run a a query on that field and use explain() - you will see that it does use the index for a search.

Regarding deleting the collection no it does not do that - it just deletes documents that are expired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to avoid indexing because there was no need for that as far as application is considered. I fear it might negatively affect as my application is write heavy.

Comment: @AmeyJah: If *not* having indexing is not a problem in your application, then it's very unlikely that *having* an index would be a problem... If you're writing tens of thousands of objects per minute, maybe, but if you need that plus very short lifetime you probably need a capped collection or a really low-overhead message queue for what you're doing.

Comment: @mnemosyn Thanks for inputs. I can't use capped collection because I have remove expired documents whereas capped collection works on fixed size of docs per collection. I will give a shot and with load testing I will be definitely able to see if there is any performance problem using ttl expiry.

Comment: @mnemosyn can u please tell me how to remove the TTL from mongodb so that it wont remove any more data in future